# Is it possible to fetch the last command ran in a parent terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pty

I am trying to programmatically fetch history from a bash terminal from within a child process (go executable). I'm essentially looking for the last N commands the terminal has run.

Flow:

1. open bash terminal PID=5
2. run a few commands (sed, rpm, gpg)
3. run go executable PID=32 PPID=5
4. fetch commands and parameters (sed, rpm, gpg) from parent process (bash terminal) and print them

The bash built-in `history` does not yield proper results when run under go/shell out.

Reading `~/.bash_history` is not accurate as the history from a bash terminal is written when the prompt is closed.

Wondering if this is possible at all?

Comment: this link may help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147563/how-do-i-repeat-the-last-command-without-using-the-arrow-keys

Comment: set `PROMPT_COMMAND='export last_command="!!"'` and then use `last_command` environment variable. NOTE: I don't know if this is a safe mechanism, w.r.t. shell injection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171348) you can save the new commands to a file with `history -a <file_path>`, then in the child process you can read the last N lines from the file (with `tail -n <N>`).

Comment: Ended up using this answer and using it in bashrc.